Tflite file conversion
How to convert a .py file with image detection modal inside .py file to tflite file in order to implement in android studio as a app?
import tensorflow as tf
 
# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("Modal.py") 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
 
# Save the model.
with open('fruits_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)



Hi @manda e You cannot convert the whole .py file. The conversion procedure is ment for saved model format or .keras format.
